# How do I know if a command needs to be run as root?

Tags: command-line, permissions, root

It is not always clearly written in the manual, is there any way to find it ?

Sometimes some commands that must be executed as root, returns a weird error message and this is also not always clear.

Comment: What are the weird error messages?

Comment: I suggest asking about the specific command you are using

Comment: Generally anything you do to affect the system or other users is going to require root powers So install/remove/update programs, edit files outside your home directory, start / stop servers on privileged ports (Apache, ftp, ssh), etc. It is not necessarily the command, but rather the effect of the command. For example you can edit any file in your home with gedit, but to edit system files, such as config files in /etc, you will need root access.

Comment: The error message should pretty much always be "permission denied". What weird errors are you getting?

Comment: A good example : the updatedb command to update the file's database returns something like "impossible to open a temporary file "for /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db"".

Comment: @terdon- typically, but not always, sometimes you get access denied messages.

Comment: The location, in this case, is a giveaway, `/var` is usually a root zone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually tell from reading (properly written) manuals when I see two things attached to the command to be run, these are:

- `#`, and
- `sudo`

these usually indicate that that file will only operate using root privileges. The `#` usually means the root account is in use, and the other (sudo) means the user should be in the `sudoers group` so they can use the `sudo` command.

The other not so obvious indicator is the `ownership` of the said file, which will only be seen if we run `ls -l` command on the file, and of course the location of the file in question. This is usually a good give away that it needs to be run as `root`. Any location outside `user home` usually needs elevated privileges to run or manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the simple and safe solution is not running anything as root. When you get an error message looking like this:

```
E: Could not open lock file /some/path/to/file - open (13: Permission denied)
```

It means the command needs root privileges.